# Can SHA2 or MD5 hash very large strings?

Tags: hash, md5, sha

I'm assuming it can't, but after searching, I cannot find information on hashing very large strings. I understand it's 256 bits, but what if a string contains a MB of information? I know I can break it into pieces. I was wondering what's the largest string I can hash with SHA2, or perhaps with MD5, without breaking it into pieces.

Comment: afaik theres no limit?

Comment: I just can't figure out how you can store a book in 64 characters, as the sha-256 provides, at least in PHP. I'm not sure if there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with large strings. Such algorithms can be applied to whole files of GB of size.

Comment: Will the result of a sha-256 still be 64 characters long? I can't figure out how that would work.

Comment: After thinking about it some, I'm guessing it's because it's irreversible. Would that be correct?

Comment: Update: I just looked up its reversibility and that is indeed why. Thanks!

Comment: yes, of course hashes are irreversible... otherwise you are looking for a compression algorithm